# `clearPackageData` removes the files(.exec & .ec) which are required to generate the JaCoCo report: Android

Tags: android, gradle, code-coverage, android-testing, jacoco

I want to clear the app states after the execution of each test case, for that, I have added: `testInstrumentationRunnerArguments clearPackageData: 'true'`.

But because of `clearPackageData`, when I run the command to generate a test coverage report it gives me the below error:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:createDebugAndroidTestCoverageReport'. 
java.io.IOException: No coverage data to process in directories 
[/Users/.../app/build/outputs/code_coverage/debugAndroidTest/connected]
```

I think `clearPackageData` removes the `.ec` and `.exec` files as well which are required to generate the JaCoCo report.
**When I remove `clearPackageData`, it generates a report properly.**

Is there any way to generate a Coverage report by keeping `clearPackageData` in `.gradle` file?
Did I miss something?
Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: It's related to this bug https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/123987001. Have you found a workaround? Thanks

Comment: Hi @TianyaoChen , I didn't find any solution for this issue, but another approach that came across was to use `System.gb()` in the `@AfterClass tearDown()` method.